# what does it mean when there is Verb+Adverb+Verb

Tags: grammar, meaning, verbs, interpretation

> おかげで僕は、辛うじてこいつらへの不信感を**誤魔化せるギリギリに留まっていられた**。

In English, would we use a comma here? I heard somewhere that Japanese doesn't use commas in those situations. I feel like the same scenario would be:

世に囁かれる星の数にも届くそれらは、一種の願望である。- I think there should be a comma between 囁かれる and 星. As in "those who are rumored by the world, those who even reach to the number of stares are kind of a wish"

Is this the same scenario? as in like:

> Thanks to it, I was able to evade the distrust to them, (and) was able to stop it with effort.

I am also thinking, why not to add te form in there? like as in

> おかげで僕は、辛うじてこいつらへの不信感を誤魔化せ**て**ギリギリに留まっていられた。

Am I understanding it right? I feel like my translation apart from being really literal, it is really goofy as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no strict rule for putting commas. In this case, the predicate part is long enough and it is reasonable to place a comma (for a pause) after 僕は.

As for the question, ギリギリに is not an adverb here, rather simply a noun ギリギリ + に meaning *at the limit*. So the sentence means *Thanks to it, I was barely able to stay at the limit where I could distract the doubts towards them*. (It is ambiguous what 辛うじて modifies.)

Answer (score 1):

ギリギリ here is used as a noun for ギリギリな／のところ, and it is modified by the clause こいつらへの不信感を誤魔化せる (or 辛うじて〜誤魔化せる if you interpret 辛うじて as modifying 誤魔化せる, instead of 留まっていられた.)

I wouldn’t put a comma there.